# How to document configuration changes from incidents

Tags: configuration-management, cmdb

how do you document changes to your configuration which were made during an incident? In ITIL incident- and configuration-management are two different processes but they are related at this point.

My ideas are:

- The information will be manually migrated to the CMDB
- The information can be exported from the ticket system and imported to the CMDB
- The incidentticket can uses entry of the CMDB to make changes directly
- The incidentticket is the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends upon whether your incidents and changes are recorded in the same system.

I use a change management system adopted from the ITIL, but our organisation isn't big enough to justify implementing all of ITIL. However we do record incidents as part of ISO9000 and ISO27000. As a result our incident recording systems and change management systems are separate, so an incident gets recorded for ISO purposes, with a high-level description of the improvement (change) recorded against it. The change information goes into the change management system in full detail. You could simply reference the incident number in the CMDB.

If you are using a single system to record both incidents and changes, then I think I would simply have a link between the two, rather than have them too closely linked.

Answer (score 0):

In ITIL is is important to know that incident management doesn't change the configuration, change management controls changes to the configuration. Change management and configuration management should work very well together ensuring changes are reflected in the configuration documentation (CMDB).

Comment: I'm aware an incident isn't part of the process for changing the configuration. But it might be necessary to change a configuration to solve an incident.

Comment: But this still implies documenting the change in a Request For Change - even if it is an "emergency" change. For critical incidents you could even document the change post, if your change policy allows that.

Comment: Sure. Don't want to argue about it. But it would be really nice, when this would happen in a somehow automagically way.